# using .find to find the space in a line Python

Tags: python, string, list

im currently using this code

```
position= line.find(" ")
```

to help me find a position for example in the case of a name: Coner John Smith

how do i single out the `smith`, currently my line of code wont help because it positions itself on the first space it finds, how do rewrite the code to find the second space in a line?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There's almost certainly better ways to solve the overarching problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your literal question is:

```
position= line.find(" ", line.find(" ") + 1)
```

What this does is find the first space in `line`, and then find the first space in `line`, starting the search on the position of the first space, plus one. Giving you the position of the second space.

But as @barmar points out, this is probably an example of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Do you want the second space? Or the last space (e.g. 'Mary Jo Suzy Smith')?

Do you want the position of the space? Or are you really just after the last word in the string? Do you care about any interpunction following the last word in the string (e.g. 'John Smith!')

Every case has a slightly different better answer.

To get the last word, you could:

```
last_word = line.split(' ')[-1]
```

To find the last space, if you need it for something else:

```
last_space = line.rfind(' ')
```

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find()` twice:

```
firstspace = line.find(" ")
if firstspace != -1:
    secondspace = line.find(" ", firstspace+1)
```

The second argument to `str.find()` is the position to start searching from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *last* space, use `rfind` or if you really want the last *word*, `.rsplit()` for it

```py
>>> "Coner John Smith".rfind(" ")
10
>>> "Coner John Smith".rsplit(" ", 1)[-1]
'Smith'
```

If you want the Nth space, you can repeatedly locate with [`.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), which can accept a start arg for where to begin finding!

```py
source_text = "Coner John Smith"
N = 2

index = -1  # search from index 0
for _ in range(N):
    index = source_text.find(" ", index + 1)
    # opportunity to discover if missing or `break` on last, etc.
```